# Can you have classes outside the Applet/JApplet class in a Java applet?

Tags: java, japplet

Can you have classes outside the Applet/JApplet class in a Java applet?

Comment: Yes you can, and in fact you should. You can have a jar file, multiple jar files, ... just like any Java application.

Answer (score 0):

You mean to have java classes in separate files in your applet project?
The answer is yes.

E.g.
Two classes
`MyApplet.java` and `Person.java`

[image]

here is MyApplet.java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class MyApplet extends JApplet implements ActionListener {
    public void init() {
          JButton button = new JButton("Click Me!");
        button.addActionListener(this);
        getContentPane().add(button);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setName("Jack");
        person.setAge(18);
        String title = "Greetings";  // Shown in title bar of dialog box.
        String message = "Hello " + person.getName() + " from the Swing User Interface Library.";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message, title,
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

And here is the Person.java class (in a separate file)

```
public class Person {
    String name;
    int age;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```